# An alternative definition of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I was wondering if the following alternative definition is the same (or weaker/stronger) than the default definition of compactness:

> A set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact if every convergent sequence in $K$ converges to a point in $K$.

versus the usual:

> A set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact if every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $K$.

It certainly applies to, say, $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ as well.

I've been searching for a case where it breaks down (i.e. one where the original definition applies but this one doesn't) but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: In $\mathbb N$  every convergent sequence converges to a point of $\mathbb N$ but $\mathbb N$ is not compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $K$ satisfies the first condition if and only if it is a *closed* subset of $\mathbb R$. For instance, $[0,\infty)$ is closed (and therefore satisfies the condition), but it is not compact.

The second condtion is equivalent to the compactness of $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=\mathbb R$ for a counterexample. Every convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ converges to a point in $\mathbb R$, however $\mathbb R$ is not compact.

If you want a proper subset, take $X=[0,\infty)$

---

However, you are close. In fact, the following is true in all topological spaces:

> A set $X$ is **closed** if every convergent sequence in $X$ converges to a point in $X$

(so, really, your condition is the condition for closedness, not compactness)

On the other hand,

> A set $X$ is **compact** if every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

which is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Observe: a set $K \subseteq \mathbb R$ is closed $ \iff$ every convergent sequence in $K$ converges to a point in $K$.